# Can I frame email based on the selected radio button in contact form 7?

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements, contact-form-7

I have a wordpress setup and I am using Contact Form & as a form builder. The problem I am facing is that, I want to frame my email based on the selected dropdown option but not getting the solutions to rectify this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this and let me know

```
[select your-recipient "CEO|ceo@example.com"
                "Sales|sales@example.com"
                "Support|support@example.com"]
```

Add this in your email tag

```
[_raw_{field name}] ([_raw_your-recipient]
```

I think it will work for you.